# How to return the boolean state value false to the parent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

***parent.tsx***

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [detail, setDetail] = useState({});
<confirmation state={setModal(true)} data={detail} />
```

***confirmation***

```
return (
    <SweetAlert
      show={state}
      success
      title="Confirm"
      onConfirm={() => {return !state}}
    >
      I did it!
    </SweetAlert>
  )
```

How to return the boolean state to false value when clicking the confirmation?
cause I'm trying to return the value to false, then I try this `onConfirm={() => {return !state}}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: At the end, what you want to do is set the Modal state to false via SweetAlert, why don't you pass the `setModal` as a prop and change the state using the prop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [always start your components with a capital letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). Secondly, a simple approach would be to pass a confirmation function as a prop, then use. So something like:

```
<Confirmation state={setModal(true)} data={detail} onConfirm={() => setModal(false)} />
```

then in the `Confirmation` component use that prop:

```
return (
    <SweetAlert
      show={state}
      success
      title="Confirm"
      onConfirm={onConfirm}
    >
      I did it!
    </SweetAlert>
  )
```

This is simple and clean and makes your `Confirmation` component more reusable, since the `onConfirm` prop can be anything

Comment: I would also add that `setModal(true)` will always return `undefined`, I think what OP really wants is to pass `modal` instead.